# How to represent 0.5% of a message value

Tags: solidity

I want to introduce transaction fees. I would like to take 0.5% of the  `msg.value`. So whenever a user calls this function I want to assign a variable the 0.5% of the `msg.value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just divide by 200.

```
uint256 fee = msg.value / 200;
```

And there is no floating point in solidity, so you get uint256 as a result, and the division result rounds towards zero.